# How can this question be more on topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, suggestions

I am not looking for a diagnosis or treatment. I am just inquiring on the benefits of snot. Can some tell me what wording I should use to be on topic?
[Do you swallow or spit?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/19073/do-you-swallow-or-spit)

Comment: Looks like the question is deleted, so I can't really see it without the required privilege. However, if you're "*just inquiring on the benefits of snot*", then write and focus the question just on that. The current title ("Do you swallow or spit your boogers or phlegm?") is so misleading that it's like looking for personal opinion. Write instead like "Is swallowing phlegm dangerous or beneficial to the body?", then add some background/context for the question clarity.

Comment: @AndrewT. I undeleted it, if you think you can make it better let me know. TKS

Comment: I don't think it is asking for personal medical advice, but it is poorly worded and shows a lack of prior research and/or support. "I heard"...heard where? Who says honey is good? What prior research can you show?